# Aggregation over aggregation

Tags: aggregate, clickhouse

I have time-series data (stock exchange trades) and I need to aggregate them by time interval: one minute, 5 minutes, 15 mins etc.
Senior time frame could be calculated from minor time frame, that is 5 x one-minutes -> 5 minutes.

I made `MATERIALIZED VIEW, AggregatingMergeTree`, which successfully calculates m1, like

`maxState(price) as price_high, countState(item_id) as trades_count`

But I don't how to make the next timeframes. If I use `maxMerge` in next view I return an incorrect result, which is fine as docs say I must use `-state` in `AggregatingMergeTree`, when I use `-State` in m5 too it complains on error.

I'd like to build series of materialized views, where minor view feeds senior one in a pipe with updates from trades

UPDATE (SQL):

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS candle_m1_state
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree() PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(toDateTime(timestamp_close_m1/1000)) 
ORDER BY (platform_id, symbol, timestamp_close_m1)
POPULATE AS
select
 platform_id as platform_id,
 symbol as symbol,
 '1m' as `candle_interval`,
 1000*toUnixTimestamp(toStartOfMinute(toDateTime(timestamp/1000))) as timestamp_m1,
 1000*toUnixTimestamp(addMinutes(toStartOfMinute(toDateTime(timestamp/1000)), 1)) as timestamp_close_m1,
...
 minState(price) as price_low,
 countState(item_id) as trades_count
from trade
group by platform_id, symbol, timestamp_m1, timestamp_close_m1, `candle_interval`
order by timestamp_close_m1;

/*The one below definitely wrong due to -State suffix*/
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS candle_m5_test
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree() PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(toDateTime(timestamp_close_m5 / 1000)) 
ORDER BY (platform_id, symbol, timestamp_close_m5) SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192 
POPULATE AS 
SELECT platform_id, symbol, '5m' AS candle_interval,
 1000 * toUnixTimestamp(toStartOfFiveMinute(toDateTime(timestamp_m1 / 1000))) AS timestamp_m5,
 1000 * toUnixTimestamp(addMinutes(toStartOfFiveMinute(toDateTime(timestamp_m1 / 1000)), 5)) AS timestamp_close_m5, 
 ...
 minState(price_low) AS price_low, 
 countState(trades_count) AS trades_count 
FROM candle_m1_state 
GROUP BY platform_id, symbol, timestamp_m5, timestamp_close_m5 
ORDER BY platform_id ASC, symbol ASC, timestamp_close_m5 ASC;
```

Comment: Would be better if you provided SQLs you use for creating tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obvious that select-query time for chain of materialized view I'd like to stick to that solution, rather than making view for each Time Frame (TF) aggregation from original data.

So solution is:

Original raw data -> TF1 materialized view (AggregatingMergeTree, **-State** suffix) -> TF2 (from TF1) (AggregatingMergeTree, **-MergeState** suffix)

Then queries form any TF1, TF2.. with **-Merge** suffix

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't try to chain views. I'd do one view per aggregation.

Also have in mind that `MATERIALIZED VIEW` is rather trigger than view.

I'd recommend:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW
    stream__source__target_5m TO target_5m
AS
SELECT ...
```

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW
    stream__source__target_1m TO target_1m
AS
SELECT ...
```

Etc.

where `target_xm` are your target tables.

Comment: It's unclear from your answer how to build `target_5m` view/table, which is my problem

Comment: How is it unclear? You create your table `target_xm` and then MV that serves as a data stream to your table. `stream__source__target_xm TO target_xm`